# Indentation after line wrap in listoftables/listoffigures using titletoc

Tags: titletoc

I am trying to better understand the *titletoc* package behavior.
I am wondering if there is a decent way to **control the hspace infront of all the "wrapped" lines**. In other words, of all lines except the one containing the label.

Is there a way to easily align it i.e. with the table label?

[image: text wrap indentation]

To test this i set up the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{table}
[0pt]                    % left margin
{}                       % above code (e.g vertical space)
{Table~\thecontentslabel:\enspace}
{}                       % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage} % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[]                       % right margin

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Magni corporis voluptatem totam vero dignissimos nisi. Laboriosam repellendus ullam sint. Iure asperiores quae saepe. Sint non commodi explicabo. Omnis reiciendis est culpa non aliquam velit earum. Eum repudiandae excepturi sapiente odio sunt.}
\begin{tabular}{ c }
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\listoftables
\end{document}
```

You can find the manual to the package here:
[manual](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/titlesec.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with the `\contentspush` command, if I've well understood what you want:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{table}
[0pt] % left margin
{} % above code (e.g vertical space)
{\llap{Table~\thecontentslabel:\enspace}\contentspush{\widthof{Table~\thecontentslabel:\enspace}}}
{} % unnumbered entry format
{\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\contentspage} % filler-page format (e.g dots)
[\smallskip] %

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Magni corporis voluptatem totam vero dignissimos nisi. Laboriosam repellendus ullam sint. Iure asperiores quae saepe. Sint non commodi explicabo. Omnis reiciendis est culpa non aliquam velit earum. Eum repudiandae excepturi sapiente odio sunt.}
\begin{tabular}{ c }
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\setcounter{table}{120}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{Magni corporis voluptatem totam vero dignissimos nisi. Laboriosam repellendus ullam sint. Iure asperiores quae saepe. Sint non commodi explicabo. Omnis reiciendis est culpa non aliquam velit earum. Eum repudiandae excepturi sapiente odio sunt.}
\begin{tabular}{ c }
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

[image]